# A zero probability Distribution from a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I have a neural network that gives out a probability distribution of 128 in length. However, the output mainly comprises numbers close to 0.
[image]
*(Probability of Strike)*

What can be the reason(s) for such a situation to arise?

> Some information about the Network:-
>
> 1. It uses LeakyRelu as the activation function.
> 2. It is a convolutional network.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are most of the observed values close to zero?

Comment: @Dave Yes, they are.

Comment: Then doesn't it make sense that most of the predicted values would be close to the true values? If I observe a bunch of small values and start making predictions that are much larger, the evidence suggests that my predictions will be poor, agreed? (There could be outside factors that influence my predictions, such as a belief that a stock with a low price will increase dramatically in value because of various reasons related to the company, but absent this information, those high predictions seem to be silly.)